# How to import just one specific library from an Swift Package?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I would like to build my own Swift Package. It depends on the Kingfisher library ([package file](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/master/Package.swift), but the Kingfisher contains more "libraries". I would like to use the "KingfisherSwiftUI" library, but I can't use it in my Swift Package, I can use only the normal "Kingfisher". I tried with specific revision or specific names, but I didn't manage to do it. The format would be something like that:

```
.package(
        url: "https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher",
        .revision("...")
    )
```

Of course instead of .revision it can be version number, etc. I didn't find a solution on the internet unfortunately.

Comment: KingfisherSwiftUI has internal dependency on Kingfisher (which is core), so can't work without it, so just don't break your head and use entire Kingfisher package as-is.

Comment: That would be great, and it would be perfectly fine - but if I simply include Kingfisher in the Package.swift file, I can't use the SwiftUI version of it in my .swift files.

Comment: Partial solution: I will try to use SDWebImageSwiftUI, it probably works, since the SwiftUI version of it is in a separated repository.